# IF URL statment opencart 3 twig files

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

can you see whats wrong with this :

```
{% if 'information_id=10' in url %}
```

Im trying to use an if statement when the url contains that string, but its not working, have i done something wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Should work as. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/9usb52). Are u sure you did pass the `url` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something in a special information page, edit `catalog\controller\information\information.php`, find:

```
if ($information_info) {
```

Add after it:

```
if ($information_id == 10) {
    $data['target_page'] = true;
} else {
    $data['target_page'] = false;
}
```

Now in `catalog\view\theme\your-theme\template\information\information.twig` file, use it:

```
{% if target_page %}
    This is target page.
{% endif %}
```

You may need to refresh modifications and clear theme cache.

Edit:

or you can pass `$information_id` from controller:

```
$data['information_id'] = $information_id;
```

And in view file:

```
{% if information_id == 10 %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, its just i have a few of these to do, ie. id=10, id=11, id=12 etc and so far, each having a different if statement

Comment: @DarkBee, thank you for your comment, but i prefer this way.

Comment: thanks @DigitCart ill give your edit a go shortly and report back! :D

Comment: @DigiCart i have given this a go, both ideas and neither worked. I've setup a test where i've done something simple like :

{% if information_id == 10 %}
this is a id 10
{% else %}
this is NOT id 10
{% endif %}

And still nothing, always shows NOT id 10...

Comment: @DigiCart ive been trying to get the URL from header.php and putting into the header.twig file. I have this in my controller : $data['currentURL'] = $this->url->link($this->request->get['route'], '', 'SSL'); and in my twig i have this : {% if 'information' in currentURL %} if i print out the result of "currentURL" its missing off the end parts, and only showing as index.php?route=information/information any idea why?

Comment: Did you clear your caches? theme cache from the admin dashboard?

Comment: @DigitCart i did, and do that anytime i make changes :)